# Java - Adding Value to Vector in Ascending, non-case sensitive order

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I'm working on a piece of working that requires me to add a value to a vector collection of string items. I need to compare a value given to an array / vector and decide where the value fits into the array based of the already sorted array.

So far, this is what I've got:

```
  public void InsertItem(String value)
  {

      if (maxlength == data.length)
      {
          GrowArray();
      }
  }
```

GrowArray is a private Void that I've already defined that grows the array if it's already full to create extra space.

What I'm struggling with is finding a way to compare the string Value to my data array to decide where it fits in.

I know that I'm going to need some sort of loop to go through the array and look at each individual element to decide if the value is bigger or smaller than the current element. I think this is going to look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i> data.length; i++)
```

If somebody could point me in the right direction that would be great!!

Thanks :)

Comment: 1. `String#compareToIgnoreCase()` or `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`  2. If you are using a `Vector` (or `ArrayList`) you don't need to cater the array reallocation yourself.  3. As you are inserting in the middle of the list, `LinkedList` maybe better.  4. As you are sorting when you are inserting, `TreeSet`, with combination of `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` may be a even better choice of data structure to use.  5. If you are writing Java, please make sure naming is done according to Java's convention.  Method names should be in `camelCase` instead of `PascalCase`

Comment: As @AdrianShum said, java automatically handle the grow part of ArrayList and Vector. In order to find the position to add the element in - yes you have to loop through the elements (or a little bit more advanced is to use a variant of the binary search) until you find the location. The second part of the for loop should be flipped (`i < data.length`) as the loop continues to iterate while the condition is satisfied. `i > data.length` is immediately violated and so your for loop never iterates.